# Saving THEN updating entity in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm trying to model progress of a data import in a `Spring Data` application but I can't get around the problem of `Hibernate` `StaleStateException`. Presumably because once the original Progress entity is saved (Id is an auto-generated UUID), it becomes detached.

Because `Spring` takes care of all of the transaction/session logic behind the scenes, I'm finding it hard to get a handle on what actually happens.

For example, I want to do something like:

```
Progress progress = new Progress();
progress.setStartTime(new Date());

int recordsProcessed = 0;
while(!importFinished) {
    // import ten records
    recordsProcessed += 10;

    progress.setRecordsProcessed(recordsprocessed);
    progressRepository.save(progress);
}

progress.setEndTime(new Date());
progressRepository.save(progress);
```

`ProgressRepository` extends `CrudRepository/JpaRepository`.

This way, if the import fails at any stage, I'll have a record of the failed import in the DB, and also I can save in batches so that the entire import isn't rolled back and needs to be rerun.

Any ideas on whether this is possible in `Spring Data`?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem is rooted at having a UUID as the ID. The relevant bit of my ID class is:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    protected UUID uuid;
}
```

And as soon as I replace UUID with a normal Long auto-increment, it all works fine.

Very painful bug - I think specifically with MySQL and how it handles storing UUIDs (BINARY(255)) - so hope this saves somebody else a lot of time!

Or anybody has any deeper knowledge of it, please share.

Comment: In fact, I've just changed it from a UUID type to a String type, and all works well.